# Usage of vector::emplace_back with shared_ptr

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct BinaryTree
{
    int element;    
    shared_ptr<BinaryTree> left;
    shared_ptr<BinaryTree> right;
};

int main()
{
   vector<shared_ptr<BinaryTree>> vecBT;

   // case I
   vecBT.emplace_back(new BinaryTree{10, nullptr, nullptr});

   // case II
   vecBT.emplace_back(shared_ptr<BinaryTree>(new BinaryTree{20, nullptr, nullptr}));

   return 0;
}

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back
template< class... Args >
void emplace_back( Args&&... args );

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr
template< class Y >
explicit shared_ptr( Y* ptr );
```

**Question**> I have compiled the above code through http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php without error.

My question is how the `case I` can pass the compiler without generating errors. Since constructor of `shared_ptr` requires explicit construction. So I expect only `case II` is correct.

Comment: You've answered yourself. You can also use `push_back`.

Comment: The case I works, but I don't know why.

Comment: @q0987 the argument of emplace_back is not a shared_ptr, so there is no implicit construction there. Rather it is a variable number of args that should be passed to the shared_ptr contructor, which can then be called explicitly..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both cases are correct, the constructor of `std::shared_ptr` is explicit, but that is exactly what is called from `emplace_back` which is just forwarding its arguments to the explicit constructor call. That's different from taking a `std::shared_ptr` as an argument and requesting an implicit conversion.

Comment: Yeah, how would `vector` construct anything otherwise?

Comment: I'm not sure about the efficiency of `std::make_shared` but it's definitely better than a naked `new` since you won't leak if the constructor throws.  EDIT:  You removed this from your post, but I think this is still relevant.

Comment: @SamCristall Had to remove it as in this specific case it can't be used as OP wanted to initialize an aggregate.

Comment: @SamCristall . I agree naked new stands out, but it would not leak if the constructor thows in the example by OP.

Comment: Caveat: Case I leaks if the vector's reallocation throws.

Comment: I think the better code here would use std::make_shared, like this:
```vecBT.emplace_back(std::make_shared<BinaryTree>(20, nullptr, nullptr));```