# initializer_list memory fault

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, qnx

I'm trying to initialize an object of my class using constructor with initializer_list.

The code is following:

```
QueryBuilder::QueryBuilder(std::initializer_list<std::string> list)
{
   std::cout << "QueryBuilder constructor begin" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "List size: " << list.size() << std::endl;
   for(const auto& element : list)
   {
      std::cout << "List element: " << element << std::endl;
      query_.tokens_.emplace_back(new NameEqualToken(element));
   }
   std::cout << "QueryBuilder constructor end" << std::endl;
}
```

The constructor is called in the following way:

```
QueryBuilder{"Path"}
```

Unfortunately, during execution of this part I have always got the memory fault.

```
Console output:
QueryBuilder constructor begin 
List size: 2857706971 
List element: Path
```

and then some random characters (program is trying to read the second element, which does not exists) finalized by memory fault.

It looks like the size of the initializer_list, passed to the constructor, is invalid.

PS I have also tried with const char* as a initializer list template parameter type.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

I'm using gcc 4.7.3 (crosscompiler armv7).

Comment: You wrote "the program is trying to read the second element which does not exist". If the range based for continues, the second element should exist. Also using `new` in `emplace_back` does not make sense, unless `tokens_` is a container of pointers.

Comment: @bluefog he is using `QueryBuilder{"Path"}` which has only one element.

Comment: That means the random chars have nothing to do with the second iteration of the loop. This should really be converted to an MCVE.

Comment: Did you read the fact that the list size is 2857706971? We dont need to see what NameEqualToken is.

Comment: @user1770426 your code produces expected output for me https://ideone.com/GMGdHr . Run the exact same code with another compiler

Comment: @bluefog the emplace_back is use because tokens_ is a vector of a shared pointers. anyway this is not the point of my questions.

Comment: `emplace_back(new ...)` = leak. Don't do it.

Comment: this is the point, I have also tried to compile and run it with 4.7.3 host x86 compiler, and it was working :/

Comment: @T.C. I believe there is no leak. The vector is a vector of shared pointers  -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822322/usage-of-vectoremplace-back-with-shared-ptr

Comment: @UmNyobe perhaps this is a problem with the cross compiler ?!

Comment: Ok, I have found the problem. Issue with implementation of the std::initializer_list.

Comment: @user1770426 It doesn't leak on the successful code path, but it will leak if the vector needs to reallocate and that reallocation throws.